# Where can I find up-to-date, online information regarding which facilities are closed in the MTR stations in Hong Kong?

Tags: public-transport, online-resources, hong-kong

I was late to some meeting as all the "Add Value Machine" machines for Octopus were under repair at the MTR station where I was hoping to charge it. Where can I find up-to-date, online information regarding which facilities are closed in the MTR stations in Hong Kong?

Comment: I think it's optimistic to assume that this question has an answer, my experience was always that this type of information was notoriously hard to come by, and when you did it was often only provided in Cantonese, if you were lucky it also came in broken and barely understandable English. Just getting this type of information for entire MTR stations is hard enough, getting it for something specific as "the self-service kiosks in every station" I think is assuming too much from the MTR Corporation.

Comment: Side note - you can top up your octopus at any 7-elevens, which exist in most of the MTR stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is such a website with such information, but [here is one](https://www.octopus.com.hk/en/consumer/octopus-cards/reload/cash/index.html) with information on the top up of the octopus card to reload by **cash**:

> #### Main Authorised Add Value Service Providers
>
> 759 Store, 7-Eleven, AEON, Arome, Café de Coral, Circle K, Vanguard, Fairwood, Mannings, Maxim's Cakes, Maxim's MX, McDonald's, Park'n Shop, Saint Honore Cake Shop, Starbucks, VanGO, Watsons, Wellcome Supermarket.
>
> [image]

> #### Selected Transportation Customer Service Centres
>
> - MTR / Light Rail* / Selected Add Value Machines
> - Airport Express Line
> - KMB
> - Sun Ferry Customer and Octopus Service Centres (Cheung Chau Pier, Mui Wo Pier, Central Pier 5 & Central Pier 6)
> - NWFB (Admiralty (East) Bus Terminus)
> - Citybus (Airport Ground Transportation Centre)

Other ways to top up your card can be found on the same link above.